# UILabel not updating in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, api, parsing

I am having an issue in which I am parsing a String value from an API and I am trying to assign it to an UILabel. I have tested updating the label in the exact same position as it is now by setting the label (lblNamedata) to a String using the format:

```
self.lblNameData.text = "hello"
```

and it has worked fine.

I currently have:

```
    if success {
        print("parse success!")

        print(strXMLData)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.lblNameData.text=self.strXMLData
        })

    } else {
        print("parse failure!")
    }
```

and this isn't working.

Below is my complete current code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var strXMLData:String = ""
    var currentElement:String = ""
    var passData:Bool=false
    var passName:Bool=false
    var parser = NSXMLParser()


    @IBOutlet weak var lblNameData: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url:String="http://www.stands4.com/services/v2/quotes.php?uid=idhere&tokenid=tokenhere&searchtype=xxxx&query=xxxx"

        let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        // Parse the XML
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
        parser.delegate = self

        let success:Bool = parser.parse()

        if success {
            print("parse success!")

            print(strXMLData)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.lblNameData.text=self.strXMLData
            })

        } else {
            print("parse failure!")
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
        currentElement=elementName;
        if(elementName=="quote" || elementName=="author" || elementName=="result")
        {
            if(elementName=="quote"){
                passName=true;
            }
            passData=true;
        }
    }

   func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        currentElement="";
        if(elementName=="quote" || elementName=="author" || elementName=="result")
        {
            if(elementName=="quote"){
                passName=false;
            }
            passData=false;
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if(passName){
            strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string
        }

        if(passData)
        {
//          print(string)
            print("work")
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
        NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
    }
}
```

UPDATE: So I believe I found the error: in my parser function I'm setting strXMLData = strXMLData + "\n\n" + string but after I delete the \n\n I can see that my label updates...why is this?

Comment: What it prints for `print(strXMLData)`? which is before `dispatch_async`

Comment: That specific statement prints out a quote from my API, such as 'If you want to accomplish the goals of your life, you have to begin with the Spirit.

Oprah Winfrey' However, I realized that if I print out the value of the UILabel, it gives me 'Optional("\n\nIf you want to accomplish the goals of your life, you have to begin with the Spirit.\n\nOprah Winfrey")'

Comment: See original post for my update...

Comment: Instead of using + you can do this: `strXMLData = "\(strXMLData) \n\n \(string)"`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after many instances of trial and error, I think I figured out the answer.

Something was up in my Main.storyboard that didn't like me creating multiple lines in the UILabel, so what I did was click on the label and navigated to the Attributes Inspector. I set the "Lines" parameter to 0 and I was able to see my text!